# Run-time error -2147417848 (80010108) after some time of inactivity

Tags: xlwings

I have not the closest idea what could cause the problem, but I encounter the following symptoms:

Sometimes after some time of not using an excel workbook connected to a running xlwings server instance, suddenly all calls to the python side fail with a runtime error.
"Sometimes" and "some time" are pretty random. It might happen after 10 minutes or it might not happen at all. I could not find a pattern yet.
It seems as if it does not happen on all computers as well.

> Run-time error -2147417848 (80010108) Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

or in german

> Laufzeitfehler -2147417848 (80010108) Automatisierungsfehler: das aufgerufene Objekt wurde von den Clients getrennt

The only way to get things working again is by closing the server instance. It is restarted without problems.

The problem has been seen with Python 3.5.3/xlwings 0.10.4 in combination with  Windows 7+Office 2010 and Windows 10+Office 2016.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Or any idea how to avoid/debug the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "closing the server instance", is that the Excel instance from where you call xlwings? And are you using UDFs?

Comment: With "server instance" I mean the running python process.
Yeps, UDFs.